# How to add 'bulma-helpers' to my HTML without npm(and yarn)

Tags: html, css

I want to add 'bulma-helpers' to my HTML without npm and yarn, so I downloaded files(css/bulma-helpers.css, bulma-helpers.css.map, bulma-helpers.min.css) and put in my css folder.

and I used link tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma-helpers.min.css">
```

but, I couldn't use any class in bulma-helpers.

How to add it without npm, and yarn?

(Link: https://github.com/jmaczan/bulma-helpers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works:

download the bulma css file from [here](https://github.com/jmaczan/bulma-helpers/blob/master/css/bulma-helpers.min.css).

then put it in css folder.

add this to your header:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bulma-helpers.min.css">
```

Comment: not Bulma, I want to add 'bulma-helpers'.

https://github.com/jmaczan/bulma-helpers

Comment: @SeungjunLee, your welcome please mark the answer as correct.